# jQuery core commit code for trim method

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me understand [this commit](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/17955cacf4e8c618ca5c2b09b0d2f43df353f683)

What is \u00A0 ?

Comment: I wonder why the caret `^` was removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code strips trailing and leading space characters in addition to non breaking spaces, `\u00A0` is the unicode point/code/number/alias for the non breaking space. You can pop up Firebug and type it out.

```
>>> '\u00A0'
" "
```

Further information about this character:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

Edit: I just tried this code in Firebug, which checks for any matches from the generated non breaking space and it matched:

```
javascript:alert( String.fromCharCode(160).match(/\s/) )
```

However, upon doing this in IE6 it returns `null`, so IE is most likely the reason for this update.

Update #2 - it looks like the removal of the caret makes this inconsistent with the previous version, because it removes not just leading and trailing spaces but spaces anywhere.

```
r = /(\s|\u00A0)+|(\s|\u00A0)+$/g;

s = '  wh  at'

s = s.replace( r, '' )
```

Outputs

```
"what"
```

Comment: Although the ECMAScript standard includes `\u00a0` in `\s`, IE does not appear to.

Comment: Here is the link which says 160 is the unicode for non breaking white space. http://wikisource.org/wiki/Transwiki:Unicode_characters_160-191

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that it's the same as `String.fromCharCode(160)` from the test case - a non-breaking space. It's making sure that trim also trims off non-breaking space characters, which may not normally match the `\s` character class.

Answer (score 1):

It is the code point for the non-breaking space character in Unicode.  The commit seems to work around a bug in Internet Explorer's JavaScript implementation where the `\s` regular expression character class does not include `\u00a0`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Unicode space character which is NOT equivalent or equal to \u0020.